# Is WCF the way to go for a RESTful webservice in MS environment

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, wcf-rest

I want to learn doing RESTful webservices. I have surfed the web some hours and think that I have a good overview over what RESTful services are and now want to build my first service-application. I have a good small project that seems perfectly suited for doing it with a RESTful webservice.

I have seen that WCF has the ability to build RESTful webservices. My question is, if it is reasonable and efficient to write RESTful webservices with WCF or if there are better suited alternatives for writing such services in the Microsoft programing environment.

(As additional information, I already have experience in using WCF, but more in using it in a RPC-way. But I don't think that this is important for my question anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF supports RESTful services via the webHttpBinding. This works but doesn't give you alot of control for working with the HTTP protocol itself (although some things got better in 4.0)

The next version is going to have a lot more support for RESTful services. The team are being very open about the [new Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/64449) so if you are not about to put something into production then I'd start with the new API

Answer (score 2):

WCF is perfectly valid and very capable of handling REST services - you won't go wrong with that!

And there are a couple of alternatives out there, too - check them out and see which one suits your needs best:

- [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)
- [OpenRasta](http://openrasta.org/)
- [RestDotNet (clients only)](http://code.google.com/p/restdotnet/)

and probably quite a few more....